# How to select the first occurence from a repeated xml field?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML. Fund occurs multiple times and inside Fund there is FundIn field. The fundId of that is unique within each Fund.
But when compared with other occurences of Fund it can be repeated.

eg:- In the first Fund the FundIn.fundId is 7 and 23 respectively. In the second Fund the FundIn.fundId is 10, 7 and 3.
If you compare both Funds, FundIn.fundId = 7 is repeating.
So I want to display only the first occurence of this id where InPerc is 24.66.

```
<Fund>
    <id>14</id>
    <FundOut>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>7</fundId>
            <InPerc>24.66</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>18.43</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>23</fundId>
            <InPerc>75.34</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>13.81</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
    </FundOut>
</Fund>

<Fund>
    <id>8</id>
    <FundOut>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>10</fundId>
            <InPerc>55</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>6.4</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>7</fundRef>
            <InPerc>20</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>18.43</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>3</fundId>
            <InPerc>25</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>36.57</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
    </FundOut>
</Fund>
```

Output -

```
<FundPrint>
    <id>14</id>
    <FundOut>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>7</fundId>
            <InPerc>24.66</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>18.43</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>23</fundId>
            <InPerc>75.34</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>13.81</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
    </FundOut>
</FundPrint>

<FundPrint>
    <id>8</id>
    <FundOut>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>10</fundId>
            <InPerc>55</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>6.4</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
        <FundIn>
            <fundId>3</fundId>
            <InPerc>25</InPerc>
            <Unit>
                <Price>36.57</Price>
                <Date>2017-06-21</Date>
            </Unit>
        </FundIn>
    </FundOut>
</FundPrint>
```

Please help with some working code.

Comment: I want to print the same thing with only first occurence of id =7 in a seperate XML. Assume any name of the output field. Using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you expect, along with any XSLT you currently have, please? It sounds like this is a grouping issue though, so have a read up on [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) if you are using XSLT 1.0. Thanks!

Comment: Do note your XML is not quite well-formed. As well as lacking a single root element, one of the `fundId` has a mismatched closing tag; `<fundId>7</fundRef>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this in the opposite way. Rather than saying you want to select the first `FundIn` for each distinct `fundId`, what you really want to do is copy all elements with the exception of the ones with duplicate `fundId` values.

Copying elements is done with the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy all nodes, so you then need to add a template to handle the case of the `FundIn` elements which are duplicates in your case. As mentioned in comments, this can be seen as a form of grouping, because grouping in XSLT 1.0 involves finding the first element for each distinct value, and then getting the remaining elements with the same value. In this case, you wish to discard these remaining elements.

So, define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="funds" match="FundIn" use="fundId" />
```

Then to discard the "duplicates", use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="FundIn[generate-id() != generate-id(key('funds', fundId)[1])]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="funds" match="FundIn" use="fundId" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Fund">
    <FundPrint>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </FundPrint>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FundIn[generate-id() != generate-id(key('funds', fundId)[1])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does assume your input XML is well-formed (and so has a single root element).

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGD for an example of it in action.